# Wordpress - Toggle box on custom options page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm building a nice options page for my WP plugin. How do I add a nice toggle box like the ones Wordpress uses on the dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article is 3 years old, but still kicks ass! - [How To Design And Style Your WordPress Plugin Admin Panel](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/07/01/how-to-design-and-style-your-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel/)

And of course - [How to Create a Better WordPress Options Panel](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to add something like the boxes in the post edit screen, you'll want to use the add_meta_box() function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Outside of the post/page editing areas, you'll need to add Dashboard Widgets (I'm pretty sure these are what you want), which you can read about here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API

If you're not looking to reproduce the collapsible widgets like the ones that exist on the Admin Dashboard page, then the other answer here has some helpful links about general plugin options page design.